# Refund unsettled transactions using Authorize.net

Tags: payment, authorize.net, creditmemo, refund

We're running into an issue with refunding Auth.net transactions that haven't yet settled.

Works:

> New Order in Pending Status > Clicking Void voids the transaction in
>   Auth.net and the customer is not charged when the batch settles at the
>   end of the day

Works:

> New Order in Pending Status > Order is invoiced, goes into Processing
>   status, wait until batch settles in Auth.net > Credit Memo can be
>   created as long as the batch has settled at Auth.net

Does not work:

> New Order in Pending Status > Order is invoiced, goes into Processing
>   status, needs to be refunded right away > Credit Memo cannot be
>   created because the batch hasn't settled at Auth.net

```
Error: the referenced transaction does not meet criteria for issuing a credit
```

I'm sure we're not the only ones encountering this issue: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/271135/

We've thought about voiding the transaction from Unsettled Transactions and using the Refund Offline option when creating a credit memo, but it seems this would leave 2 transactions (original charge & refund) in Magento and just the voided transaction in Auth.net reporting.

**What are some ways others have worked around this issue?**

Update: Looks like "authorization reversal" is available in EE – http://chepri.com/new-enterprise-release-packed-with-features-you-dont-want-to-miss/

> Authorization reversal. This feature allows the release of funds put
>   on hold for unsettled orders. This feature is useful when a customer
>   decides to cancel an order and contacts the administrator. In this
>   case, the administrator will be able to release the amounts on hold
>   without the required waiting period. (This feature is not available
>   for American Express cards.)